# which package for \oiint symbol

Tags: fonts, symbols

I have some code which uses the `\oiint` symbol. However there are many packages that provide this command. Most of for special fonts. I am using `lmodern` however and want a package that provides the symbol matching to `lmodern`.

I have found so far `wasysym` with option `[integrals]`, `mathabx` and `esint` package.

Comment: `esint` is designed to match with Computer Modern, so it should look just fine with `lmodern`.

Comment: I've included the esint package, but LaTeX keeps thinking the \oiint command isn't defined. I've double-checked that the package is installed. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 15):

If I go to the [detexify site](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) and draw the double-integral-with-circle symbol, the answer I get is `\oiint` from the [esint](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/esint/) package. The package also provides the command `\varoiint` for a perfectly circular-shaped circle symbol. (Sounds rather circular, doesn't it?!)

Aside: If the `esint` package is loaded, the macros `\iint` and `\oint` are modified relative to the definitions provided by the `amsmath` package. With `\iint`, the two integral symbols are spaced more closely, and with `\oint`, the circle is enlarged. (Note that the *shape* of the basic integral symbol itself is still the one that's provided by the Computer/Latin Modern math font.) Speaking purely for myself, I find both changes to be ok, and even quite good. However, it's probably worth pointing this out explicitly, if for no other reason than to avoid any surprises by unsuspecting users of the `esint` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esint} % various fancy integral symbols
\begin{document}
\[
\int \iint \oint \oiint \varoiint 
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, March 2018: If you use LuaLaTeX and the `unicode-math` package, you wouldn't need to load any particular package to get access to macros such as `\iint`, `\oint`, and `\oiint` -- the corresponding symbols should be provided by just about all unicode-based math font. Here's how the symbols look when using 11 different math fonts. (Aside: I chose the math fonts purely based on their ability on my TeX distribution (MacTeX2018).)

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\blurb{$\displaystyle \int\ \iint\ \oint\ \oiint $}
\usepackage{unicode-math,booktabs}
%% Load 11 math fonts
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=LM]
\setmathfont{Stix Math}[version=Stix]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[version=XITS]
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[version=Stix2]
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[version=Cambria]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[version=Asana]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[version=Pagella]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[version=Termes]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[version=DejaVu]
\setmathfont{Neo Euler}[version=Euler]
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}[version=Libertinus]

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
Latin Modern Math  & \mathversion{LM}        \blurb \\ \addlinespace
Stix Math          & \mathversion{Stix}      \blurb \\ \addlinespace
XITS Math          & \mathversion{XITS}      \blurb \\ \addlinespace
Stix Two Math      & \mathversion{Stix2}     \blurb \\ \addlinespace
Cambria Math       & \mathversion{Cambria}   \blurb \\ \addlinespace
Asana Math         & \mathversion{Asana}     \blurb \\ \addlinespace
Pagella Math       & \mathversion{Pagella}   \blurb \\ \addlinespace
Termes Math        & \mathversion{Termes}    \blurb \\ \addlinespace
DejaVu Math        & \mathversion{DejaVu}    \blurb \\ \addlinespace
Neo Euler      & \mathversion{Euler}     \blurb \\ \addlinespace
Libertinus Math& \mathversion{Libertinus}\blurb
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

For people in need of a triple closed loop integral:

Using `\oiint \hspace{-13.5pt} \int` I was able to create an `\oiiint` replacement. It uses the `\oiint` from the `esint` library.
 (`\usepackage{esint}`)

Below you can see a before and after. It's a little crammed but it works! This is the only way I got this to work in MikeTex with the default font Computer Serif Modern.

[image: Before and after]

Comment: This doesn't answer the current question.

Comment: IMO it's perfectly fine to answer a slight extension of the question. Better to keep them in one place then having them asked by different people with untraceable cross-links.