# XeLaTeX Double closed path integral?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols

How can I write a double closed path integral? I have searched and I have found only single closed loop integral.

Comment: You mean something like the Unicode character `∯` (U+222F)? This would require »[unicode-math](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math)«.

Comment: If you're using Computer/Latin Modern, you could do `\oiint` from the `esint` package.

Comment: Do you mean ∯ (U+222F SURFACE INTEGRAL)?

Comment: Yes I mean that symbol. Which is the command that produces it?

Comment: @Adam It's `\oiint`, as already pointed out

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: @Adam Did you load `unicode-math`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symbol you're looking for is called `\oiint`, but you need either `esint` or `unicode-math` for accessing it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % also loads fontspec

\begin{document}
\[
\oiint \quad \oiiint
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want (or can't) load `unicode-math`, then `\oiint` is available through `esint`, as explained in [which package for \oiint symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37747/which-package-for-oiint-symbol)

If you want to use `amsmath` package as well, you should load it before `esint` package to avoid LaTex errors like `Command \iint already defined`.

---

How did I find the name? I searched for "integral" with a program that knows all Unicode (I use UnicodeChecker on Mac OS X). Going through the list I found U+222F. Then I looked in `unicode-math-table.tex`: from a shell I did

```
less `kpsewhich unicode-math-table.tex`
```

and searched for `222F` which pointed to the line

```
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"0222F}{\oiint}{\mathop}{double contour integral operator}%
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you can find `\oiint`  and `\oiiint` in these packages:

- esint
- mathabx
- tx/pxfonts
- MnSymbol
- mathdesign

If you use Computer Modern, the think `esint` is OK.

You can take a look at `The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List` ("variable-sized maths operators) to have an idea.

Comment: @egreg; Sorry, once more, I forgot to check before posting. You were quicker than me.