# Getting a proper `\oiint` symbol (not bitmap)

Tags: fonts, unicode-math

How can I typeset a proper `\oiint` symbol?

I can only find bitmap workarounds or ugly variations.
Using the package `esint` with this minimal setup:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{esint}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\oiint_A \bm{F}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

…results in unusably ugly rasterisation:

[image: close-up of rasterised surface integral]

With `\usepackage[integrals]{wasysym}`, the all integral symbols are replaced with uglier, shorter alternatives, which isn’t acceptable for my use.

Using `unicode-math`as per [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162771/xelatex-double-closed-path-integral?noredirect=1&lq=1) breaks the `bm` package. To fix this, used the package `mathastext` as per [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17265/compilation-problem-extended-mathchar-used-as-mathchar-with-mathastext%20%E2%80%9Cthis%20question%E2%80%9D), but this seems to break absolutely everything. I am beginning to seriously doubt LaTeX.

Please help me.

---

**Edit** Here is the contents of the file `MWE.log` on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/6vhbR2dm) when compiled with `PdfLaTeX`.

Thanks.

Comment: Your MWE produces *no* rasterization when I compile it.

Comment: bm and unicode-math don't get along too well, but mostly you don't need bm at all if using unicode-math as most of the alphabetic bold symbols (such as `\bm{F}` in your example) are available in the uniocde-math fomts directly (and can be accessed using `\symbf` from unicode-math)

Comment: Your example should work fine. Can you show the log-file of a compilation with pdflatex?

Comment: Ok @UlrikeFischer, I’ve added a link to the log-file. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your advice has worked, thank you. I guess I will just need to remove the `bm` package and replace all occurrences of `\bm` with `\symbf`. Or should I redefine `\bm` → `\symbf`? If so, do you know how?

Comment: your problem is `/Users/Joseph/Library/texlive/2016basic/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/esint/esint10.600pk` the map file to tell pdftex to use scalable fonts seems not to have been installed

Comment: `\newcommand\bm{\symbf}` would work to define an alias.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle. `unicode-math` works perfectly, even though the integrals use a slightly different font. But how can I install the map file? Does that point to an incomplete `esint` installation?

Comment: @Jollywatt You should use TeX Live Utility and install `esint-type1`. I usually recommend to install the full MacTeX, rather than the “basic” one, which misses so many things.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, that is exactly what was missing. Now everything else is working like normal.

Comment: Should I post an answer to this question, just to say my installation was missing `esint-type1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Type1 (vectorized) version of the fonts used by `esint` is available in the TeX Live package `esint-type1` that you should install with TeX Live Utility:

[image]

If you do the same on your machine, you will see “Not installed” for the bottom one. Install it.

If disk space is not a big problem for you, it's better to install the full MacTeX, so dependency problems like these will disappear.

Comment: Thanks. Can I install MaxTeX through Tex Live Utility, or should I install it straight from http://www.tug.org/mactex/? It’s true, I’m always falling into dependency rabbit holes.

Comment: @Jollywatt You have to do the install from TUG. But maybe it's better waiting for the 2017 release, due June.