# Esint package - proper \oiint symbol (not bitmap) on MikTeX and Windows

Tags: miktex, integral, esint

When I want to print integral symbols such as `\oiint` using the `esint` package, the integral signs look ugly:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{esint}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\oiint_{\partial R} F\cdot n d\sigma=\iiint_R \mathrm{div} Fd\tau
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I am aware that this question has been asked earlier [here (Getting a proper `\oiint` symbol (not bitmap))](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366385/getting-a-proper-oiint-symbol-not-bitmap), but the person who asked this question uses TeX Live and Mac.

How can I solve this? I am using MikTeX 2.9 and Windows 10. I hope you can tell me how to solve this without redefining all sorts of commands or loading many other packages. I read that some parts of the package may not be (fully) installed - how should I install them?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is the `esint-type1` installed on your system? If not, can you use the MikTeX Package Manager (MPM) utility to install the package?

Comment: Yes, I think so. When I search in my MPM, I find a package with the name `esint`, and with the title `esint10 in Type 1 format`.

Comment: It works fine for me in miktex. If you have the font installed then probably the map file is not up-to-date. Run in the miktex console, user mode, the task "refresh font map files".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Run in the miktex console, user mode, the task "refresh font map files".

That definitely was good advice! I will post here how I solved the problem.

For some reason, I did not have a MikTeX console on my computer, only MPM, MikTeX Update and MikTeX Settings. In one of those (I don't know which one anymore), I could update the package database, which I did. This solved the problem.

However, after I had done that, Windows couldn't find any of the three aforementioned MikTeX programs. I do not know the reason for this. I have been fiddling around a bit, and now Windows starts the MikTeX console whenever I start any of these three programs. It hasn't created any problems so far.

Thank you all very much for helping me!

Edit: to get rid of the dead links and to make sure I have the most recent version, I decided to reinstall MikTeX (a bit overkill :)). The same error with the ugly integral sign occurred again, here's more precisely how I fixed it. 
I ran the MikTeX console as an administrator (but I think user works as well). Then, under "taks" on the toolbar, I clicked "update package data base". That did the trick.

Comment: miktex has removed the old three configuration tools and replaced them by the miktex console. It is quite possible that the change leaves some dead links in the windows menus, simply remove them.