# "Pixel zoom" of an integral using amsart and esint

Tags: metafont, resolution, zooming, bitmap, esint

A simple question:

I have this minimal working example where I use `amsart` with `esint`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esint}
\begin{document}
\[\varointctrclockwise\limits_{\text{loop}}\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l}=0\]
\end{document}
```

but the result is a **bad resolution** with pixels making the zoom of TeXworks and directly with the `pdf`.

[image]

[image]

Is there a conflict with `amsart` and `esint` package? If I use this MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\oint_{\text{loop}}\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l}=0\]
\end{document}
```

I have not problem.

[image]

**EDIT:** I have seen that into my `MikTeX` distribuition I have these `esint` packages:

[image]

I think that I have the contents of this package https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ps-type1/esint (see previous image).
What is the exact link where must I take these postscript fonts esint?
[Here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/esint.zip) or where are they exactly?

**Related: my procedure to install new fonts**

[Latest MiKTeX: suggestions on how to install new fonts using the MiKTeX Console](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419957/latest-miktex-suggestions-on-how-to-install-new-fonts-using-the-miktex-console)

Comment: I can't recreate your problem based on your MWE. Everything looks fine to me, no rasterization. The problem doesn't seem to be caused by the packages.

Comment: @Jojo But I don't understand the reason but I have updated all recent packages. The classic integrals are fine.

Comment: My crystal ball suggests me that you're running MiKTeX and for some reasons the PFB versions of the `esint` fonts have not been installed. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/473015/4427

Comment: @egreg Does your crystal ball predict my future if it true, would you borrow it for a short time? :-) :-) I use MikTeX but now is inactive the console. I'm using TeXworks. PFB versions I don't know what they are :-( I'm sorry.

Comment: @Sebastiano The end of the LaTeX output is probably very telling. What precedes `Output written on`. Among others, I have `</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/esint-type1/esint10.pfb>` and there is no pixellation. PFB is a file format for vector fonts (PostScript).

Comment: @frougon Wait, I see if I can put the output...I use MikTeX console not texlive. Now I'm refreshing font map and database.

Comment: @frougon `<C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/ljfour/public/esint/dpi657
\esint10.pk><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.
pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/P
rogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb><C:/Program Fil
es/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on p.pdf (1 page, 34141 bytes).
SyncTeX written on p.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on p.log.`

Comment: The font that becomes pixellated is no doubt one that was created with Metafont.  The PFB version recommended in other comments is the correct solution, as it is a scalable outline font.

Comment: @egreg I see, with lot of humilty, that there is written the resolution `dpi657 \esint10.pk`. The problem exist.

Comment: Yep, this is it. `esint10.pk` is your culprit. PK fonts are bitmap fonts, typically generated from MetaFont sources. You probably have a problem of *font map* configuration: what tells the driver how a font for TeX-the-engine should become in the output (PDF probably here).

Comment: @barbarabeeton You know that I am a scarce user. :-) I have understood your comment but what is the solution? :-)

Comment: This has nothing to do with `amsart`.  Please remove that tag.

Comment: @frougon All answers are welcome ...always...I not know if I have a problem of font map configuration and how fix it.

Comment: I don't know MiKTeX well enough, but you may need to “regenerate font maps.” [This](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/advanced.html#psfonts) could maybe help. You may want to find the `psfonts.map` and look for a line containing `esint10`... which probably won't be there until you've solved the problem.

Comment: @frougon Peraphs I have understood....but with the use of the console? :-( Into Map xyz.map what is must put, please?

Comment: Perhaps first find this `psfonts.map`, verify `esint10` isn't mentioned there and then try to reinstall the `esint` package looking very carefully at all the log output you can have for this operation in order to make sure you don't miss any problem when MiKTeX tries to update its map file (which I believe it should do in such a case)?

Comment: @frougon I have done a research but psfonts.map not exist.

Comment: Hmm... then either `initexmf --mkmaps` will help, or you need someone who knows MiKTeX better than me... Plus, the tool has a `--admin` mode, and I'm not sure if you should use it here. You can run `initexmf --admin --update-fndb` before, I think it can only help.

Comment: @frougon Have faith :-)

Comment: The conditions in which `--admin` should be used are given [here](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/initexmf.html). “Using this option requires a shared MiKTeX setup, i.e., MiKTeX must have been set up for all users.” So, it depends on how you manage your MiKTeX installation.

Comment: @frougon For this moment I have leaved the question. For me it is not very important esint package. In the future...I will try. Thankkkkkkkkkkkkkkk you everybody.

Comment: @frougon I think to solve the problem in the future.....the solution is to find the exact .zip fonts with the complete map, tds, ecc. of esint. :). I have also give thank you in others words :-) Goood night also for you.

Comment: The theory is: a font package providing vector fonts ships one or more `.map` files. When installed, this or these map files get incorporated (with possible massaging to account for differences between formats) into a big one that has the info for *all vector fonts of your installation* (e.g., psfonts.map, pdftex.map, etc.). This is what “updating the font map/map files“ means.

Comment: @frougon I have installed oneday classico.tds (Optima clone font) and other fonts himself. I am very tired. I delete my close vote and good lucky forever. You can delete your previous comment...I'm doing everything I can to write notes for my students, but it won't help. I'm very tired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the esint-type1 package by clicking on the plus in the miktex console (user mode is fine)

[image]