# Double integrals in amsmath/euler package?

Tags: amsmath, euler

I found this guide on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_symbol) but I cannot use them directly, for example when I try to use `\oiint` it says that the control sequence is not defined.:
[image]

I tried using packages `amsmath` and `euler` but it did not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\section{Gauss's law}
\[
  \Phi_{E} = \oiint \vec{E} {\cdot} d\vec{A}
\]
\end{document}
```

Any way to get these symbols?

Comment: `\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}` should help.

Comment: I think you need to \usepackage{asmssymb}, too. / Would be easier, if you add the Wikipedia link next time ;-)

Comment: OK that makes sense. Would this also work for `euler` (and  potentially) other font faces?  (I have added the wikipedia link)

Comment: Try with `esint` package. Beside it, exist may others which support `\oiint` symbol. See Mico answer on question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37747/which-package-for-oiint-symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking well the first column (named unicode) the type-format of the integral seem taken from `wasysym` package. You can see the analogy.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}
\section{Gauss's law}
\[
  \Phi_{E} = \oiint \vec{E} {\cdot} d\vec{A}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]